# Mongoose : Middleware : Pre : Find : Parameters?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-middleware

How do I pass the request context to the Pre find function in Mongoose?

```
 schema.pre('find', function(next,req,callback) {
        this.filter = req.query.param;
        next(callback);
    });
```

The above is my middleware. Am using it as below

```
User.find({},req,function(err,results){});
```

But my middleware function doesn't get the req object?

Comment: Mongoose schema doesn't have middleware, but hooks, and hooks cannot be used as middleware, middleware is express router thing

Comment: Trigger an event would be an alternative. Other than that as @MedetTleukabiluly perfectly worded, mongoose pre & post are hooks not middleware.